# Как передать параметр в компонент Vue js

Tags: vue.js

Использую Vue js. Есть компонент, который принимает входные параметры:

```
props: {
    errorText: String
},
```

В шаблоне другого компонента вызываю:

```
<my-component
    :errorText="{'Текст ошибки' : isError}">
</my-component>
```

Но на странице выводится следующее:

> {'Текст ошибки' : doc_number.isError}

А не просто

> Текст ошибки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно из-за того, что вы указываете тип пропса String, а передаете объект, попробуйте вот так:

```
<my-component
    :errorText="isError ? 'Текст ошибки' : ''">
</my-component>
```